# How do i find out how many individual letters there are in a word in python?

Tags: python, pyscripter

I'm using pyscripter to create a hangman game. I have managed to get everything to work except one thing. This is that once i have found the correct word the script needs to match this to the secret word. This would usually be easy but the way i have done it leaves gaps in the string.
What i want to do is using the number of letters in the secret word; when i enter a letter it looks for that letter and adds how many times the letter appears in the secret word. i.e. the letter "P" in APPLE appears 2 times, therefore adding 2 to a separate string. if the word was "APPLE" the program would be looking for 5 correct letters.
This way i can make an "if" statement and end the game once the numbers of correct letters guessed matches the length of the secret word.
This is the program i am using : http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/1HZ38RzykuE/maxresdefault.jpg

Does this make sense, I've been pondering on it for a while so it may be jumbled.
Thank you if your able to help.

This is the code i am using:
(blanktotal is the length of the secret word)

```
         else:
            if letter in secretword:
                letterscorrect = letterscorrect + 1
                os.system("cls")
                if letter not in guessedletters:
                    os.system("cls")
                    for x in range(0, len(secretword)):
                        if letter == secretword[x]:
                            for x in range(len(secretword)):
                                if secretword[x] in letter:

                                    hiddenletter = hiddenletter[:x] + secretword[x] + hiddenletter[x+1:]
                    guessedletters.append(letter)

                else:
                    print("")
            else:
                print("")


        for letter in hiddenletter:
            print(letter, end=' ')
        print("")

if letterscorrect == blanktotal:
            os.system("cls")
            print("")
            print("congratulations you have won!!!!")
            print("You are now the master of HANGMAN!!!!!")
            print("")
```

Comment: A picture of your PyScripter screen is *not* your source code. We can't help you without the code.

Comment: the picture i uploaded is just to make sure that others know the program i am talking of, i wasn't sure if there was another program that people use.

Comment: A different way to do this is to just eliminate duplicates by making a `set` out of the string. Then, when the number of guessed letters is equal to the `len` of that `set`, all letters have been guessed.

Comment: ok! I will try that. i will see whats easiest.

Comment: Please add the source code to your original post so we can understand what you are actually doing.

Comment: i should have added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the count() method to count the number of occurrence of a letter.

```
secret = "Apple"
secret.count('p')
```

gives

```
2
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're just looking for the [`count`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) method:

```
>>> s = 'APPLE'
>>> s.count('P')
2
```